# Understanding starvation freedom and wait-free methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm reading [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/general/terminology.html) and now I'm at the section about non-blocking guarantees. Here is what is said (emphasized mine):

> A method is wait-free if every call is guaranteed to finish in a
>   finite number of steps.
>
> [...]
>
> as each participant can progress after a finite number of steps (when
>   the call finishes), ***wait-free methods are free of starvation***.

The emphasized is not quite clear to me. Starvation is defined earlier in the documentation as it is impossible for participants to make progress (some are starved).

Now, if multiple threads call the same wait-free method they cannot be starved. Does it mean that even if the method is blocking and wait-free, stavation never happens? I just cannot picture exact details about wait-free method?

For instance, if a method calls ***blocking I/O*** methods, is it wait-free? I'd say no, it isn't. But what about this one:

```
public class MyClass{

    private static Object mutex = new Object();
    private int sharedInt = 0;

    public void isItWaitFree(){
        synchronized(mutext){
             ++sharedInt;
        }
    }

    //The rest
}
```

I'd say it depends on the `//The rest`, because the one might involve `mutex` acquision for indefinitely long amount of time.

What would be the example of true wait-free method?

UPD: I suppose that wiat-freedom methods are ones which use non-blocking techniques like `AtomicXxx` classes or if we can guarantee that the `mutex` held for *finite* amount of time.

Comment: "the method is blocking and wait-free" how can a method be both?

Comment: There's no such thing as a wait-free _method_.  Wait-freedom is a property of an _algorithm_.  Often the entire algorithm is contained within a single method, but not always.  If the "wait freedom" of `isItWaitFree()` depends on `//The rest`, then that probably means that `//The rest` is part of the same algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my understanding, wait-freedom is a property of not just the function/method, but also the environment where it is going to be executed. Since starvation can happen due to "unfair" scheduling algorithms, wait-freedom can be achieved

1. only for a non-blocking method
2. only in case of a scheduling approach where the effective priority of queued tasks is gradually raised proportional to their waiting time, until they get to the top of the queue and are given the chance to complete their job.

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively, the wait-freedom property/privilege of the method may be somehow exposed to the scheduler, so that it can schedule such tasks separately.